# как развернуть react и node на одном порте

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

CORS не позволяет делать запросы с 1 localhost на другой localhost и я решил развернуть и реакт и ноду на одном порте только не могу найти инфу как подскажите пж

Answer (score 0):

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Для начала, установите http-proxy-middleware :

```
$ npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
$ # or
$ yarn add http-proxy-middleware
```

Потом, создайте src/setupProxy.js с подобным содержимым:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

Это перенаправит /api на сервер ноды на другом порту.

Comment: да это понятно там именно cors не позволяет отправлять запросы на другой порт https://sun9-69.userapi.com/s/v1/ig2/bGG0fJusMntx4otHQqWIfMzFgpGWclh8QTOAQE_vQZAHzrVJhhbJ32FLVeLgejd8Ggh_PeQwVcvDogOBVsvdLLg4.jpg?size=549x224&quality=96&type=album вот скрин

Comment: так подмена на внутренний прокси решает эту проблему

Comment: в target нужно указывать порт ноды или реакта? вот что пишет Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: значит в ноде поставь no-cors